# Aligning image to center inside a smaller div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `width:100px` and `height:100px` (say)
Inside that, there is just an image, for which height is always fixed to `100px`.

I want to make the image horizontally center.

Here there are 3 cases:

1. image's width is equal to div's width, no issues
2. image's width is less than div's width, I can use `margin: auto` here
3. image's width is more than div's width

I want the center part of the image to be visible inside the div.

means, if image's width is `120px` and as div's width is `100px` and `overflow:hidden`
I want image's 10th px to 110th px to be visible (so, the `left: 10px` and `right: 10px` of image are hidden under the div )

**Is this possible through some CSS property?**
(I dont know the width of image which is loading! so I want it to be dynamic.
Also want to avoid javascript side calculations to find the extra amount of width and giving `margin-left:` -ve value bla bla.. )

Also, I can't give the image as `background-image` for the div!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x62nV/ (and [without `overflow: hidden`](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x62nV/1/) to easily see the centering)

This will work in all browsers, with the possible exception of IE6.

For `.imageContainer > span`, the `margin-left` is derived from the `width`, and the `width` is an arbitrary number which controls the maximal image width that will be supported. You could set `width: 10000px; margin-left: -4950px;` to support really wide images, if required.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="imageContainer">
    <span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/f0f/fff" /></span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.imageContainer {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.imageContainer > span {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: -450px; /* -(width-container width)/2 */
}
.imageContainer > span > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot!
by adding these below 2 properties, am able to achieve vertical align center also for the small images (when compared to div)
.imageContainer{
    line-height:100px;
}
.imageContainer > span > img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

:-)

Comment: Great answer, nice usage of jsfiddle :D