# Absolute centering of content in CSS div even when content overflows enclosing div

Tags: css, xhtml

I am trying to get text absolutely centered inside an html div, even when it is wider than the enclosing div.

The text is center-aligned as long as it is smaller than the enclosing div, but when it exceeds the width of the enclosing width it gets left-justified (I checked this on recent versions of Chrome, FF, IE).

I have this:

```
    <style>
   .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: silver;
    }

    .line {
        position: absolute;
        width:100%;
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="line">
            PLEASE ALIGN ME TO THE CENTER
        </div>
    </div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/acc4u/5/ for a live version of the code above - You can decrease the font size to see how this is is center-aligned when narrower.

I could use the `left:-nnpx` css attribute and that would get the job done, but that would be extremely inflexible as I would need to calculate the text's width to compute the offset. Since I intend to animate the size of the text, this would need to be calculated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Aligning image to center inside a smaller div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149747/aligning-image-to-center-inside-a-smaller-div/8150196#8150196), I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/x62nV/2/.

It seems fine, except for that on WebKit browsers, when you move the mouse up and down, the text is very shaky.

Comment: Very nice! I love the javascript snippet as well.