# How to put an image inside of a smaller div in the middle?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aligning image to center inside a smaller div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149747/aligning-image-to-center-inside-a-smaller-div)

I have a problem which points to CSS 3. Please see the part of my HTML code:

```
<div id="main" style="width: 320px; height: 400px;">
   <img src="test.jpg" height="400" />
</div>
```

I don't know the real sizes of the test.jpg file (width can be different - the file is dynamic). I want to have the image in the middle of id="main" (I don't care, that the left & right part of the image will be out of range - it's even better). How can I do that ?

Comment: do you need only  horizontal or also vertical centering?

Comment: I don't see any CSS3 here, unless you're saying your image and div are involved in some transform or animation where this problem shows up. Could you elaborate?

Comment: now it looks like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3074090/_temp/1.png but I want to put the image like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3074090/_temp/2.png

Comment: @BoltClock♦: You can now use your magical powers.

Comment: Is it not an option to simply make the image a background image?

Comment: no, I would prefer <img>

Comment: Just use `text-align: center;` on the `div`...

Comment: @jeroen: That won't work once the image width exceeds the container width - it'll simply overflow to the right (or the left, if in RTL mode).

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, that's true...

Answer (score 4):

As long as you specify any `width`, you can center by adding `margin:auto;` . This isn't CSS3.

```
<img src="test.jpg" style="margin:auto; width:200px;display:block" />
```

Comment: I don't want to resize the image (width 200), just align to the center

Comment: but I don't know the real sizes, so I can't set the width to i.e. 200px

Comment: try setting the image width as 100% instead of a fixed number of pixels

Answer (score 3):

this will do the work

```
<div id="main" style="width: 320px; height: 400px;background-position:center;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url('test.jpg')">

</div>
```

Comment: did you try this method?

Comment: Yes, but I would prefer to use <img>. I have solved the problem using jquery.

Comment: could you share with us?