# Center a div, partially off-screen

Tags: html, css

I am looking to center a large div that reaches beyond the screen. This concerns having a large `.container` `div` about `1920px` wide, with the actual content being centered inside `.container` in a `div` with a class of `.content`, about `1200px` wide.

I manage to center one in the other, but centering `.container` when it's boundaries are off-screen is not working. It puts the left border against the left border of the browser.

```
[ |   [content]   | ]

Legend:
| = screen edge
[ ] = div edge
```

`.content` must always be centered within `.container` so that the background's position related to the foreground does not change.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <section></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean... this seems like a terrible idea. I'd set container to 100% width and content to `margin: auto` and I know that doesn't solve your problem if container is 1920 wide, but what you want just seems like a bad idea. I can think of a possible solution with javascript but not with CSS only.

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149747/aligning-image-to-center-inside-a-smaller-div#8150196) that might work for you. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x62nV/285/).

Comment: Will .container always be 1920px wide?

Comment: @3rror404 yes, I have a background that is 1920px wide, and the content overlaying always needs to have a static position on top of that, even if the user is using like a 1280x1024 monitor.

Comment: @Leeish I'll take any solution really. Even JS. I thought it'd be possible with CSS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the width of `.container` you can do this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -960px; /* Negative margin half of the element width */
}
```

---

Here's a (dirty) jQuery alternative if you didn't know the width of `.container`. Esssentially the same result, you just need to calculate the negative margin by halving the width:

CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var elWidth = (($('.container').width())/2)*-1;

$('.container').css('margin-left', elWidth);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yw4qN/1/)

Comment: So far, this seems to be working quite perfectly.

My final code:

.container {
 width: 1920px;
 height: 1080px;
 background-image: url(images/bg.png);
 position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -960px;
 z-index: -10;
}

Comment: I have the static width, but I'll definitely keep this in mind.